# Corda persistence and models with collection

Tags: hibernate, corda

I use corda persistence mechanism for store some data.

The model looks like this:

```
object UsersDataSchema

object UsersDataSchemaV1: MappedSchema(
    schemaFamily = UsersDataSchema.javaClass,
    version = 1,
    mappedTypes = listOf(
        User::class.java,
        BankAccount::class.java
    )
) {
      @CordaSerializable
      @Entity
      @Table(name = "user")
      data class User(
          @Id
          @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
          val id: UUID,

          @Column(name = "name", unique = false, nullable = false)
          val name: String,

          @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
          @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
          val bankAccounts: List<BankAccount>
     ) {
        private constructor(): this(UUID(0L, 0L), "", emptyList())
     }

      @CordaSerializable
      @Entity
      @Table(name = "bank_account")
      data class BankAccount(
          @Id
          @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
          @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
          val id: Long? = null,

          @Column(name = "number", unique = false, nullable = false)
          val number: String
      ) {
          private constructor(): this(number = "N/A")
      }
}
```

If I use model with collections(OneToMany) in any flows, I get this error after successful flow finish:

```
FiberDeserializationChecker - Encountered unrestorable checkpoint!
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection, could not initialize proxy - no Session
bankAccounts(UsersDataSchemaV1$User)
dataObject (co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Stack)
stack (net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you resolve this issue somehow?
I'm faced with absolutely the same issue and didn't know haw resolve it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corda make a very brief mention of this in the [Flow Documentation](https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-V4.3/flow-state-machines.html) under the "Persisting flows" heading.

The short of it is that you need to perform any operations that may use the `@Entity` objects which have collections inside a method not marked `@Suspendable`, and ensure that those objects don't escape that method (e.g immediately use the result of a query to find the actual State in the vault and return that instead, or create and return a simpler dummy dataclass).

This happens because Kryo will attempt to serialize every object on the stack when the function suspends (such as when it goes through `subFlow`s or `receive`s), and deserialize it later. Many of Hibernate's types when dealing with queries are some form of autogenerated proxy object to support metadata and lazy initialization. As Hibernate sessions aren't preserved between serialization and deserialization, when Kryo deserializes one of these proxies and they are later used, lazy initialization will fail if it is used (such as in the case of fetches/joins on collections), and it will fail fast. Even annotating the join fields to fetch eagerly will not work, due to some sort of internal interaction.

We mitigate this by simply ensuring that these objects never end up on the call stack in a `@Suspendable` function.

Comment: I didn't get which solution should be?

Comment: Hello. Yes, we found a solution. We use [CordaService](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.6/api-service-classes.html/).